# Vim - autocommands ignored while in autocommand code

Tags: vim

As the title says, are autocommands not triggering while executing an autocommand?
For example, I have tested opening a new window with 'new' inside a VimEnter autocommand and it didn't trigger the WinNew autocommand. On the other hand, when I just put 'new' in the .vimrc file, it triggers the WinNew autocommand.

Comment: `:h autocmd-nested`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from autocmd.txt:

> By default, autocommands do not nest.  If you use "`:e`" or "`:w`" in an
>   autocommand, Vim does not execute the `BufRead` and `BufWrite` autocommands for
>   those commands.  If you do want this, use the "nested" flag for those commands
>   in which you want nesting.  For example:
>
> `:autocmd FileChangedShell *.c nested e!`
>
> The nesting is limited to 10 levels to get out of recursive loops.